# MQTT TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mqtt

```
export default function App() {

    MQTT.createClient({
            uri: 'mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883',
            clientId: 'id1',
            //tls: false
        }).then(function(client) {
        
        client.on('closed', function() {
            console.log('mqtt.event.closed');
        });
        
        client.on('error', function(msg) {
            console.log('mqtt.event.error', msg);
        });
        
        client.on('message', function(msg) {
            console.log('mqtt.event.message', msg);
        });
        
        client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connected --------------------------->');
            client.subscribe('/data', 0);
            client.publish('/data', "test", 0, false);
        });
      
        client.connect();
        }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        }); 

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Hello World!!!!</Text>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I imported MQTT this way:

```
import MQTT from 'sp-react-native-mqtt';
```

This library should be for react native and I copied the code from https://npmjs.com/package/sp-react-native-mqtt

Comment: Can u share the whole file code please?

Comment: it means `MQTT` doesn't exist, maybe you did miss to import the library  via CDN or module

Comment: MQTT is a backend technology., with the library for Nodejs. You shouldn't be putting it in your React frontend

Comment: @OneCricketeer The MQTT client can happily run in the frontend (MQTT over Websockets will run from the browser, the OP is trying to use native MQTT which won't work)

Comment: I imported MQTT this way: import MQTT from 'sp-react-native-mqtt'; This library should be for react native and I copied the code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-react-native-mqtt

Comment: I looked for a library compatible with mqtt tcp because I need in react native. Does anyone know which one works?

Comment: Topics should not start with a leading `/`

Comment: That library is for React Native, yes. Are you writing code for the browser or a mobile device? If for mobile, there are other instructions on the NPM page

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, I'm writing code for mobile device, I think I have followed all the steps on the NPM page, the only thing I don't understand is: Don't forget to include import com.tuanpm.RCTMqtt.*; with the other imports at the top.